# UWP Application - Displaying data from SQL table onto Data Grid or Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio, uwp

I am having some trouble displaying data onto a data grid or even a list box with data from an SQL Server table.
I was able to do display the data on load in a DataGridView with a Windows Forms App but not with UWP. I am using the same connection string that I used in my Form App if that makes any difference.

In the Mainpage.xaml I have the datagrid as this:

```
<Custom:DataGrid x:Name="dataGridView1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/> 
 <ListBox x:Name="lbData" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="803,428,386,434"/>
```

In .cs page:

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Server=(local);Database=databaseName;" + "User=someuser; Password=somepassword";
    
SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

string query = "Select * FROM TABLE_NAME";
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                conn.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(reader);



                dataGridView1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                lbData.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

                reader.Close();

                cmd.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
```

I read that DefaultView is required when adding an itemSource to a grid view.
Instead of under page loaded, I also implemented this code under a button click to see if any data would show but I got a: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible error.

Wondering what would be the best fix for this and how I would be able to display the information from my SQL Server table. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve data from the SQL Server database and show it in DataGrid, first you need to create a class whose properties corresponding to the column name of the data table, then use [SqlDataReader.Read()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) method to read data for each row and convert each record to a class object, finally write them to a collection. Please refer to the following code.

```
  public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public ObservableCollection<DataInfo> results;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            results = new ObservableCollection<DataInfo>();
            string ConnectionString = "Data Source =xx;Initial Catalog =xx;User ID=xx;Password=xx";
            string query = "Select * FROM timedemo1";
            try
            {
                using(SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        using(SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            cmd.CommandText = query;
                            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {

                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    DataInfo data = new DataInfo();
                                    data.name = reader.GetString(0);  //first column datatype:(nchar(10))
                                    data.time = reader.GetDateTime(1); //second column datatype:(date)
                                    results.Add(data);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception:"+ ex.Message);
            }           
          myDataGrid.ItemsSource =results;       
          myDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;    
        }
      
    }

    public class DataInfo
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public DateTime time { get; set; }
}
```

More info could be found here.[Retrieve products from the SQL Server database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases#retrieve-products-from-the-sql-server-database)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, finally got around to trying to troubleshoot. I tried to incorporate your suggestion and also looked through the Microsoft document.  When I run the application, only the headers of the table display in the DataGrid but no rows of data. I am not too sure why that is.

Comment: I tried recreating the application again, but only the headers of my SQL table are showing no data is displayed. Looks like it just populates the header based on my DataInfo class methods (string, DateTime). 100% sure I have rows of data as well.

Comment: It seems that there is something wrong with the process of the data binding. You need to notice that I have a table in SQL database, it has two columns named **Name**, **Time**, their type is `(nchar(10))`, `Date`. Therefore, I created a **DataInfo** class with two specified properties corresponding to the table and use `reader.GetString(0)`, `reader.GetDateTime(1)` to get the first, second column data. That means you need to use `reader.GetInt32(ColumnIndex)` to get data and add a property with **Int** type in DataInfo class if you have a column with **Int32** type in the table.

Comment: The key point is creating a correct class corresponding to the table and using the suitable [SqlDataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=netframework-4.8#methods) method to get the data of each column. If you do as the above, then you could check if the **results** collection has data.

Comment: I use the same connection details on my Console Application but for UWP I am getting these errors. This is what I get on the debug console:
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.SqlClient.dll
Exception:A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: To add on, my SQL Server is running and I have added the configurations that was listed in the above Microsoft document. I assume then the data binding is fine? But the issue is with the connection. Not sure why I had no issues with a Web Form or Console Application but with UWP this issue occurs.

Comment: The exception usually means that the SQL Server instance can’t be found. Before you connect to your database, please make sure the SQL Server configuration is right. First, ensure that you've enabled **TCP/IP** for SQL Server. Then make sure that your **SQL Server Browser service** is running.

Comment: I had both those services configured as shown in the document but I still received the errors. However, I have tried again now and I am able to access the database! Maybe something needed a restart. Thank you for your help! I am able to access the stand alone sql server (either with "DataSource=." or Server=(local) ) but when I try to access the local DB (@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB) I get the errors.  Thanks again.